# Commerce: Flat Rate per Product

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

Using Drupal 7 and Commerce, I created a field on my products (/admin/commerce/products/types/product/fields)

New price field called "Shipping Price" (field_shipping_price)
So now I can apply a static flat rate to each product when I create the product nodes.

How can I use this value to calculate the shipping value for the order?  I assume it would be done with Rules or a custom module, both work for me. I am having trouble finding the right fields to get it working (with rules).  Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Are you using the commerce_shipping module? That woud get you a long way. https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping

Comment: @olyN Yes I am.